# Is it safe to use new Image() to do click tracking?

Tags: javascript, onclick

I'm developing a click tracking system to monitor the usage my company's product on external (customers) sites. I would like to be able to tell my customers to simply put a javascript call on any element using onclick.

My current approach is using an Image() object to create a request to my tracking server. This works fine, but I'm having some doubts as to whether or not this is safe. If I put this on a link, can I be sure that my request is being sent before the browser follows the link? My testing suggests that I cannot.

So I tried using onclick="return MyFunction()" which returns true when and only when the image has finished loading. However I cannot load the image while blocking the thread in Myfunction(), since javascript only runs on one thread. So I have to use a blocking call which blocks the request for say 500 ms which would decrease the risk of the request not being sent, but reduce performance on the site.

Another approach would be to use callbacks or the like to handle the page switch after the image has been loaded. Something like:

```
<a href="http://www.google.som" onclick="return MyFunction(this)">Link</a>

<script type="text/javascript">

function MyFunction(theLink)
{
var img  = new Image();
img.onload = function(){ location.href=theLink.href; }
img.src = "http://www.myserver.com/trackclick";

return false;

}

</script>
```

This would require that my customers implement the function as required above. Moreover, if the image for some reason does not load (if my server is down for instance) the customers site will break.

I checked Google's ga.js and it suggests that they use some sort of blocking rather than event handling and callbacks. But then again, their code is intentionally hard to understand.

My questions are:

1. Can I be sure that a request using new Image().src in an onclick event is fired before the browser follows the link, or would I need to use a delay?
2. Does this behaviour differ between browsers and browser versions?
3. Is there a "best practice" way of doing click tracking that I haven't found yet?

EDIT: 4. Does anyone know how Google Analytics does it? They seem to use the onclick="MyFunction()" approach, without either return statements or callbacks.

Comment: With the code you posted, you can be sure if you make the link unique to avoid reloading from cache.. make sure to handle the `onerror` event as well to avoid breaking the users site..

Comment: @Gaby Do you know if onerror are available in all browsers? I've read that using onload is not browser-safe. When I've tested it seems to work fine with all modern browsers (even IE7+ if I remember correctly)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following up on @Gaby's comment, you should use some way to avoid cached requests, you could use the Date object for that. You should also implement an onerror behaving the same way, so you don't break the site. The code should look something like:

```
function MyFunction(theLink){
   var img  = new Image();
   img.onload = img.onerror = function(){ location.href=theLink.href; }
   img.src = "http://www.myserver.com/trackclick?d=" + new Date().getTime();
   setTimeout(function{location.href=theLink.href; }, 350);
   return false;
}
```

This way, if your server is down, it won't record the user's click, but the site behaves normally. Adding a unique query string to the image's url will prevent cached requests.

If onload or onerror fails to execute because of browser incompatibilitie, you can also use a setTimeout to redirect the page to the desired url. that way, if none of the events fire in expected time, you have the ultimate fallback.

Comment: Ah, yes my URL is a bit more complex and involves cache preventing. I just simplified for the sake of example. But thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: Thank you, this is a solution that would solve the problem. I'm still interested in how Google manages to do it without either return statements or callbacks though. Maybe they attach a click event and then cancels an event or something?

Comment: @Gaby Really? Using the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header? How broad is browser support for that (IE<8)? When I check with dev console in Chrome it looks like an ordinary image request.

Comment: @JoelWKall, nope.. not really :( I was wrong in my comment..  sorry for the confusion.. It is indeed just an image. I was browsing through the code and noticed a point where they were doing some xmlhttprequest, and was too quick to comment.. They follow the same principle as the one you describe.. have a look at http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&answer=55527

Comment: @Gaby OK, I was not aware that they had another implementation standard for outbound links. What about internal links then? Their event-tracking is using the onclick="_gaq.push([arrayOfThings])" syntax. http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html

Comment: @Gaby Maybe they put the data in a cookie and then sends the request when the user lands on the other page? That's why they cant do the same thing with outbound links. Am I on to something?

Comment: Seems like its something like that. I ended up using the code André propsed. Thanks a lot for all the help!

Comment: I'm working on something similar, and wanted to mention that `location.href = theLink.href` should probably account for `target` attributes on the links.  This approach also will cancel any subsequent click handlers attached to the link.  This is a difficult problem to solve.